# Open installed app on android phone in react native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, deep-linking

I want to open microsoft teams and yammer app installed on my phone

```
Linking
.openURL('vnd.youtube://') //works
.openURL('skype://') //works
.openURL('facebook://') //works

.openURL('msteams://') // does not work
.openURL('microsoftTeams://') // does not work
.openURL('microsoft-teams://') // does not work
```

This is an example of code that works for youtube, what is the microsoft teams and yammers equivalent?

need help! please :(

Answer (score 0):

if your looking to open other applications from your own it may be easier to use intents with the following

https://github.com/lucasferreira/react-native-send-intent

```
SendIntentAndroid.openApp("com.google.android.gm").then(wasOpened => {});

// You can also specify arbitrary intent extras to be passed to the app
SendIntentAndroid.openApp("com.mycorp.myapp", {
  "com.mycorp.myapp.reason": "just because",
  "com.mycorp.myapp.data": "must be a string",
}).then(wasOpened => {});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the following reference regarding creating MS Teams deeplinks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links

For Yammer please check the following one: https://developer.yammer.com/docs/ios-and-android

Comment: Is this necessary? I just need to open the apps without any links attatched, just the main page of the apps. Please let me know